# Why is the calling place of functions in my code important?

Tags: javascript

The only difference between the two codes is where I call the "de ()" function. I left the codepen links below to understand exactly what the problem is. The problem is that when I click the button in the faulty code, it gives me the same color, not the different color, but if I run the function as in the correct code, it gives a different color when I click on each button. I searched on the internet but couldn't find an answer. Why is this happening?
it's working code: https://codepen.io/BerkayAkgurgen/pen/wvoKPGM
it's problem code:  https://codepen.io/BerkayAkgurgen/pen/rNWOYep

```
// it's working code
eventListener();

function de() {
    const denemeArray = ["#f2f", "#000000", "#ff0"];
    let be = Math.floor(Math.random() * denemeArray.length);
    return denemeArray[be];
}

function eventListener() {
    document.getElementById("deneme").addEventListener("click", function () {
        const choice = de();
        de();
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = choice;
    });
}
```

```
// it's problem code
eventListener();

function de() {
    const denemeArray = ["#f2f", "#000000", "#ff0"];
    let be = Math.floor(Math.random() * denemeArray.length);
    return denemeArray[be];
}

function eventListener() {
    const choice = de();
    document.getElementById("deneme").addEventListener("click", function () {
        de();
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = choice;
    });
}
```

Comment: If you initialize `choice` outside of the event handler, it will never change; it will retain whatever value it had from that first call to `de()`.

Answer (score 3):

In the problem code, the value to variable 'choice' is set only once. The function de() is called on every click, but the return value is not used.

```
function setEventListener() {
const ORIGINAL_COLOR = de();
document.getElementById("deneme").addEventListener("click", function actualEventListener() {
    const THIS_COLOR_IS_NEVER_USED = de();
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = ORIGINAL_COLOR;
});
}
```

Comment: What I was asking is why this is so I realized it's been called only once anyway

Comment: @OyeeBerkay when you call a function and assign the result to a variable, that's all that happens. The variable does not become some kind of magic thing that calls the function whenever it's referenced.

Comment: The de() function is called on every click. 
In the broken version the return value is discarded, and the original value of 'choice' is used.

In the working version, the return value of de() is stored to 'choice' const, and then used to set the background color.

Comment: And the function called 'eventListener' is confusingly named. that function attaches the other, unnamed function as event listener. See the edited function names